# Heroku React WebSocket connection failed

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, websocket

I have a React app I made with create-react-app deployed on Heroku here http://www.morganecom.me/. Source here https://github.com/DavidMorgan92/ecom-client.

When the page loads there is an error in the console about a WebSocket connection failing. Console error stack trace:

[image]

My app doesn't use web sockets directly, it seems to be something to do with webpack. I've tried searching for information but all I've found is people discussing the problem where they're using web sockets directly.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do about it?

Comment: Please post the source code here in your question itself. Otherwise it is very difficult to do a discussio.

Comment: @RBT I understand what you mean but the error is not originating with my code but with webpack. It doesn't occur on a local instance, only on the Heroku deployment. So I'm not sure which piece of code would be helpful for me to post.

However, today I am unable to reproduce the error. When I navigate to the deployed website the console shows no websockets requests at all.